# Kafka heartbeat threads blocking

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-camel

we have a WebSocket server which creates a separate consumer group for each WebSocket client so each WebSocket user can receive updates from a Kafka topic independent of each other. we use camel API for creating Kafka consumer(groups) which uses Kafka native Java APIs anyways so this has nothing to with Camel but mentioning camel just an FYI.

from using JMX and JMC monitoring we have found that Kafka heartbeat threads get blocked and a number of counts for blocked threads go up exponentially for each new consumer group that gets created every time a new WebSocket client joins. attaching a screenshot for more details. wondering why Kafka consumer/heartbeat is causing such high thread contention affecting overall application behavior ending up running out of juice.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This problem sounds like it could be Apache Camel related.  I've had Camel behave in really erratic ways when talking to Kafka in the past (in my case, the Camel consumers were committing the exact same offset hundreds of times per second, for every consumer, completely overwhelming a massive 12-node kafka cluster with the commits to `__offsets` topic).  Simply updating to the latest Camel version made that problem go away. Make sure that you are using the latest available Camel version.

Another way to validate would be to quickly fire up the same number of command-line kafka consumers, without Camel running, and see if the heartbeats behave that way.  If they don't, then I'd be almost certain this is Camel bug/configuration issue.

Comment: what camel-kafka version were you running on before when you saw erratic behavior? what camel-kafka version fixed your issue? I am running camel-kafka version 2.19.4